# Пустое место под списком

Tags: html, список

Есть многоуровневый [список.](http://prntscr.com/cji7r5)

Т.е. при не раскрытом списке под футером остается пустое пространство.
Если добавить всплывающим спискам `<ul>` стили:

```
 max-height: 500px;
 overflow-x: hidden;
 overflow-y: auto;
```

то появляется [аномалия](http://prntscr.com/cjibqp) в виде пустого пространства под списком. Под футером соответственно пропадает.

Помогите разобраться.

Comment: без хтмл/цсс гадать мы не будем.

Comment: Вот [ссылка на сайт](http://pokaremont.ru/). Просто не представляю как вам показать этот километровый список :)

Comment: ul третьего уровня имеет большую высоту, соответственно он растягивает темный бекграунд ul второго уровня. логику бекграундов переработайте.

Comment: Что Вы подразумеваете под логикой бэкграундов? Можете объяснить в двух словах? Или ткнуть носом где копать?

Comment: проще сделать список третьего уровня (тот что длинный по высоте) в 2-3 столбца как на http://rozetka.com.ua/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В общем решил данный вопрос с помощью jquery. А именно: отобразил первых 20 элементов, и добавил `<li class="btn-show-more">` и скрыл все последующие элементы. При клике на созданный элемент показываю скрытые элементы. Может кому понадобится:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('ul.first li ul.second li ul.third li').eq(20).after('<li class="btn-show-more">Показать больше...</li>');
    $('ul.first li ul.second li ul.third li:nth-child(n+23)').hide();
    $('.btn-show-more').click(function(){
        $('ul.first li ul.second li ul.third li:nth-child(n+23)').show();
        $('.btn-show-more').hide();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Нужно просто через CSS сделать так чтобы при нажатии на объект стиль менялся на block, а пока а потом обратно в none.Можно это реализовать в Jquery: 
`$('click').click(function(){
    $('.tab').toggle();
});`
Ну и понятное дело вставить свои значения.Надеюсь я правильно понял вопрос.
P.S. В CSS должно стоять `display:none;`

Comment: вы видимо не правильно поняли вопрос. Меню всплывает при наведении мышкой. Проблема в другом: на третьем уровне очень длинный список и он уходит вниз за футер, т.е. когда список скрыт - то под футером получается пустое пространство.